# How to print an array updated by setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, settimeout

The task is to write a function to reverse an array of numbers and print out each number every 2 seconds. Also print the reversed array in the end.

I wrote the following to achieve this, but it is a bad method, since I need to calculate the number of seconds in each setTimeout and also take extra steps to determine whether the for loop has reached the last iteration.

Is there a direct way to pause 2 seconds after each iteration and then print the reversed array in a synchronous way?

```
const reverseNumbers = (array) => {
  const n = array.length;
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let res = [];
    for (let i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(array[i]);
        res.push(array[i]);
        if (i === 0) resolve(res);
      }, 2000 * (n - i));
    }
  });
};

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let myPromise = reverseNumbers(array);
myPromise.then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Is there a question here?  If you already have working code and are looking for coding improvement suggestions, then investigate https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and be sure to follow the posting rules there (they have a very specific set of rules).

Comment: I didn't downvote.  Not sure who that was, but probably because you didn't actually ask a question here.  Please clearly state a question for exactly what you're looking for help with.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks. My account was blocked again from asking further questions... I have edited the question to improve it and received an answer. Perhaps I am a beginner in this area but I feel the question is not totally trash. Any suggestion how I can have the ban lifted? T_T This is very discouraging.

Comment: I don't have anything to do with a new question ban. There are numerous guides on asking questions such as [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to ask a great question on stackoverflow](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-ask-a-great-question-on-stack-overflow-965d9cd8846d) and [Asking better questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/).  That last one also talks about blocking new questions from users with a history of low quality questions.  I'm not making any judgement on your questions, just giving you info to read.

Comment: There's certainly a question here, but as written it's currently unclear/opinion-based. Can you clarify what you mean by "better" and "convoluted", in objective terms? Fewer lines of code, no for loop, etc.?

Comment: @TylerH thanks for your suggestion, I have revised the question.

Comment: @hehe the update definitely provides more detail, but still fails at the critical point: what is "straightforward" meaning here? What is the actual problem you are having here? Is this code working fine and you just have a gut feeling that it could be better? Or is there some functionality that is not being achieved, or some objective metric for your organization/team that is not being met?

Comment: @TylerH The original code I posted takes extra effort to calculate the number of seconds for each setTimeout. It also takes extra running time in each iteration to determine whether the for loop has reached the last iteration. Things may be worse for more complicated situation. It is not the expected solution. The accepted answer solved my problem. In essence, I did not know how to pause for 2 seconds and then continue with the remaining code in a synchronous way. I edited again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way to return an updated value after setTimeout?

Promisify `setTimeout` on its own, then use `async`/`await`:

```
function delay(t) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, t);
  });
}
async function reverseNumbers(array) {
  const n = array.length;
  const res = [];
  for (let i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    await delay(2000);
    console.log(array[i]);
    res.push(array[i]);
  }
  return res;
}

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const myPromise = reverseNumbers(array);
myPromise.then(console.log);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is the solution I was thinking about but did not know how to implement. Looks like reverseNumbers() returns an array, but it actually returns a Promise object?

Comment: @hehe It's an `async` function, so it always (immediately) returns a promise, which is resolved with the `return` value of the function body when that has finished executing.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way of doing it. No idea, whether this is shorter or better, but in any case: it works.

```js
function rev(arr){
 let r=arr.slice(0),
  intv=setInterval(()=>{
   if(r.length) console.log(r.pop());
   else {
    clearInterval(intv);
    console.log(arr.reverse())
   }
  }, 2000);
}
 
rev([0,8,15,47,11]);
```